# Assortment Bundle install in symfony 2.2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2, sylius

I want to install assortment bundle in symfony 2.2.1.
I added
"sylius/assortment-bundle" : "*" in composer.json

and run 
composer  require sylius/assortment-bundle:*

but showig error:

The requested package sylius/assortment-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
blem 2

Answer (score 1):

Please try with `sylius/assortment-bundle": "0.1.*@dev"`.